# Internet Explorer fails to set cookies with same name

Tags: php, internet-explorer, http, cookies, http-headers

I just fired up a VM with Internet Explorer 11 to test this out. Try running the following php in Internet Explorer:

```
<?php
setcookie('mycookie', rand(), 0);
setcookie('mycookie', rand(), time() + 60);
setcookie('sessioncookie', rand());
setcookie('expirecookie', rand(), time() + 60);
```

1. Use the inspector to inspect the resulting response cookies.
2. Refresh the page. Cookies that were received on the previous request should be sent on the next request.
3. Internet explorer fails to keep any record of the 'mycookie' cookie. The other two are set fine. This only seems to happen when you set a session cookie, and then set a cookie with an expiry and the same name.

I can't seem to reproduce this in any other browser. Is this something that is in the HTTP spec, but Chrome and Firefox are being lenient about?

Here are the response headers for cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: mycookie=101636679
Set-Cookie: mycookie=158533464; expires=Tue, 07-Jul-2015 17:39:03 GMT; Max-Age=10
Set-Cookie: sessioncookie=1777324234
Set-Cookie: expirecookie=1229727377; expires=Tue, 07-Jul-2015 17:39:03 GMT; Max-Age=10
```

Note that everything works as expected if you reverse the order of the first two setcookie directives:

```
<?php
setcookie('mycookie', rand(), time() + 60);
setcookie('mycookie', 'latest', 0);
setcookie('sessioncookie', rand());
setcookie('expirecookie', rand(), time() + 60);
```

This will set the 'mycookie' value to 'latest'.

Comment: setcookie() basically just does a `header()` call internally. I'm not sure if it's doing a header replacement if you try to set the same cookie multiple times. If not, it may actually be sending out multiple cookie headers, and IE for some reason is only honoring the first encountered, which happens to be the `0` time delete cookie.

Comment: When I inspected the response, both headers are set. So there are two separate Set-Cookie headers for 'mycookie'. If it is indeed the case that IE only honours the first Set-Cookie header, then the cookie should be retained as a session cookie. Setting a value of 0 for expiry in PHP does not send an expiry at all. I will ammend my question with the headers. I'm not sure why IE throws out the cookie entirely instead of at least keeping it for the session.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works well in Internet Explorer,

```
setcookie("mycookie", rand(),time()+5*24*60*60 );
```

Comment: This works fine for setting a cookie, but doesn't address the problem above where setting two cookies with the same name fails.